# Windows 8 External Monitor Missing Resolution Choice

Tags: windows-8

I just updated to windows 8 and I'm running bootcamp.

The maximum resolution setting for my external monitor under Windows 8 is 1440 x 900.  On Windows 7 I had 1920 x (I forget).

I tried updating the display driver (BenQ), but that did nothing.

Does anyone know how to increase my resolution?

Comment: Have you tried updating your GPU driver? BenQ sounds like the name of your display, but your GPU would be something like Intel, AMD, or Nvidia.

Answer (score -1):

I went into OSX mountain lion and re-did the bootcamp software.  I think that overwrote the drivers.

All is well now with my display.  The track pad doesn't work, and I have some language problems, but at least I'm getting the full resolution.